# Looping in R to create calculated delta columns

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a dataframe with baseline variables and the same variables after a period of time.
I'm trying to loop in order to calculate delta columns.

```
delta <- function(df, lenght) {  
half<-lenght/2
for (i in df[,(half+1):(lenght)]) 
{   df[,i]- df[,i-half]  
df }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, it still doesn't work; plus i'm not able to give a name to the new column.
Thanks in advance,
A

Comment: Could you please provide data to make this reproducible?

Comment: You may be interested in the function `diff()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you're just trying to calculate the delta between 2 columns you can just do `column1-column2` since R is a vector language

Comment: @CephBirk Diff is for lagged/iterated differences within a vector. He's taking the delta between columns, I believe

Comment: @Hack-R yes, you're right

Comment: @Hack-R transpose then diff?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do without more information about your columns and your goal with the logic you have in your question but this is how you calculate the delta between 2 columns within a data frame in R:

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),v2 = c(5,4,3,2,1))

v3 = df$v1-df$v2

#-4 -2  0  2  4
```